# Filemaker 12 how to do a calculation of multiple fields

Tags: filemaker

I set my variable to bring an `Inventory record` (Inventory Table) over to my `Production layout` (Production Table) inserting that variable into its `ID` field. That works.

My problem is that I have `Item, Color, Weight, Basis, Size` fields that I need to pull the info from my `inventory table` to put in the Production layout using that `ID` number. (I know about portals but I would need multiple portals for this since I will be "importing" other info from my Inventory records and my customers records).

*EDIT* I think I might have answered my own question. I set variables for all fields I want to bring into the Production layout, Then use a script to set those fields by Calculation. Does that seem like the best way to go about this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relationship would work better.

```
Set $productionId = Production::id
Go To Layout "Inventory"
New Record
Set Field Inventory::productionId = $productionId
// now the relationship is valid between inventory and production
// you can copy fields over from the Production table, 
// or just reference them using the relationship
```